# Manejo de SQLException con java y postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas para iniciarme en el manejo de `PostgreSQL` a través de java, en el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
    String user = "user12";
    String password = "34klq*";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()")) {

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostgresCommand.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Pero aparece el siguiente error en el log:

> Error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de
>   datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1,
>   if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or
>   host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)

```
abr 06, 2018 8:28:04 AM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl log
Error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
ADVERTENCIA: SQLException occurred while connecting to localhost:5432
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)

abr 06, 2018 8:28:04 AM org.postgresql.Driver connect
GRAVE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)

abr 06, 2018 8:28:04 AM database.PostgresCommand main
GRAVE: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)
```

Entiendo que esto surge debido a que la base de datos no existe pero si estoy capturando la excepción porque sigue arrojando el error? Como puedo solucionar esto?

Estoy tratando de verificar si la base de datos existe, en caso de que no exista crearla, esta parte la haré después por ahora me gustaría entender por qué no puedo capturar la excepción.

capturando todas las excepciones:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "130117";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()")) {

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostgresCommand.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

obtengo lo siguiente:

> abr 06, 2018 8:44:54 AM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl
>   log ADVERTENCIA: SQLException occurred while connecting to
>   localhost:5432 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la
>   base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be
>   ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs
>   and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf) Error:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos
>   «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if
>   the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host,
>   port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)
>
> abr 06, 2018 8:44:54 AM org.postgresql.Driver connect GRAVE:
>   Connection error:  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe
>   la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be
>   ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs
>   and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)
>
> abr 06, 2018 8:44:54 AM database.PostgresCommand main GRAVE: FATAL: no
>   existe la base de datos «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding
>   to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check
>   database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos
>   «testdb» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if
>   the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host,
>   port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   database.PostgresCommand.main(PostgresCommand.java:33)

Comment: `lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);`

Comment: si la capturas, y puedes verlo en los logs de la aplicacion, fijate que comienza con tu mensaje de `Error:` de `System.out.println("Error: "+ ex)`

Comment: Si es correcto, entro al bloque del catch pero debería solo imprimir mi mensaje no el resto.

Comment: entonces no logees el stacktrace con `lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);`

Comment: le he agregado // para comentarlo y dejar solo el System.out.println() pero de igual forma muestra como si no captura la excepción o como si dentro de ese bloque surgieran otras excepciones.

Comment: Que import haces para poder utilizar la SQLException???

Comment: dice que no existe la base de datos. verificastes eso?

Comment: import java.sql.SQLException; he pensado agregar import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException; pero ppuedo capturar estas excepcion en SQLException.

Comment: Si la base de datos no existe porque solo quiero capturar la excepcion cuando eso suceda. es decir detecto que la base de datos no existe entonces la creo, el codigo de crearla lo hare despues, pero por ahora me gustaria capturar y controlar cuando la base nde datos no exista.

Comment: Tu código no tiene problemas. La traza del error se está mostrando en pantalla porque: la imprimes explícitamente dentro del cuerpo del `catch`, o porque tienes configurado en tu aplicación algún mecanismo de logging cuyo nivel permite mostrar las trazas que registra el driver de JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no me preocuparia mucho por esas entradas de log, no son tuyas, son del driver.

Al parecer el driver de postgres genera multiples mensajes de log cuando ocurre un error para la misma excepción:

```
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
```

En `ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl`:

```
log(Level.WARNING, "SQLException occurred while connecting to {0}", se, hostSpec);
```

Y en `Driver.connect`:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Connection error: ", ex1);
```

Tu bloque `try-with-resources` funciona bien, y captura la excepcion correctamente.

Comment: Eso estoy haciendo, he continuado y hasta los momentos no me ha detenido el programa, es decir, genera esos mensaje pero continua su ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca he programado en java, pero segun el articulo: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp la sintaxis correcta es:

```
try{
    code...
}catch(Exception e){
    code exception
}
```

El codigo que muestras tiene la sintaxis:

```
try(code...){
    code...
}catch(Exception e){
    code exception
}
```

No estoy seguro de que tu codigo tenga la sintaxis correcta.
Entonces lo correcto seria

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "130117";

        try{

             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()")
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(PostgresCommand.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```